# Function that convert currency, the code passes 8/9 tests, i don't know what is missing to pass the last test?

Tags: algorithm, if-statement

This is the problem:
Let's create a convertCurrency function that will accept parameters, such as amount in hryvnia('s), exchangeRate, name currencyName of desired currency and return string Give them {{x}} {{currencyName}}('s). The function has to check that an employee filled in the parameters correctly and return the message Enter valid data in case amount and/or exchangeRate contain negative values or zero. If the result is not an integer, round the value to two decimal places.

and this is the code that I wrote:

```js
function convertCurrency(amount, exchangeRate, currencyName) {
  // write code here
  const result = amount * exchangeRate;

  if (amount && exchangeRate > 0) {
    if (Number.isInteger(result)) {
      return `Give them ${result} ${currencyName}('s)`;
    } else {
      return `Give them ${result.toFixed(2)} ${currencyName}('s)`;
    }
  } else if (amount || exchangeRate <= 0) {
    return 'Enter valid data';
  }
}
```

and this is the Error that I get:
Function 'convertCurrency' should return 'Enter valid data' when amount = -500, exchangeRate = 0.14, currencyName = 'peso'

Comment: Please. No images of text or code or error messages. Type it.

Comment: In the error message on the right of the image it says it should return the string "Enter valid data" if the amount is `-500`, ... - your solution does not cover that condition. Can you exchange a negative value, let's say `-500 €` ?

Comment: yes but in the same time it passes other tests that have the negative values.
Exemple:
TEST 6 PASSED
Function 'convertCurrency' should return 'Enter valid data' when amount = -145, exchangeRate = -0.55, currencyName = 'ruble

Answer (score 1):

Your line `if (amount && exchangeRate > 0)` is being parsed in your head as "amount > 0 and exchangeRate > 0".  But it is parsed by JavaScript as "(amount) and (exchangeRate > 0)".  Which is evaluated as "(-500) and (0.14 > 0)", therefore "-500 and true", therefore "true".

You need to actually put `amount > 0 && exchangeRate > 0`.

Comment: okay now i understand it much better, thank you!!